# how to append a string variable to a href link in a tpl file

Tags: python, html, smarty, bottle

I have a file called `registration_email.tpl` which is passed into `bottle.template()` as `email_template` as the following:

```
    email_text = bottle.template(email_template,
        username=username,
        email_addr=email_addr,
        role=role,
        creation_date=creation_date,
        registration_code=registration_code
    )
```

So I got some variables like `username` and `registration_code` that I can use in `registration_email.tpl`.
Because this `.tpl` file's goal is to configure an email containing a link to let the user to click on the link to finish the validation of registration, I need to find a way to append the `registration_code` to the `href` in order for `@bottle.route('/validate_registration/:registration_code')` to get the value for the wildcard `:registration`, which I can later used in the function for validation.

So I was wondering how can I append `registration_code` to a `href` link in a `.tpl` file?

For example if `registration_code`'s value is `5057896`, then I need the link to be `mywebsite.com/validate_registration/5057896`. I would appreciate if anyone could provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already passed the variable to the template, now you just need to call it.

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/validate_registration/<% registration_code %>">Link here</a>
```

Using `<% %>`, you can pass any python code directly into the template, and reference variables you've specified when the template loads.

Edit:

For calling a single variable, double curly braces work too:

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/validate_registration/{{ registration_code }}"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you that works! I should have tried this obvious approach by myself first..